# How to navigate to the top of a div?

Tags: html, css

I understand the simple

```
<a href="#sol" class="sol"></a>

<div id="sol">lorem ipsum</div>
```

but that navigates to the center of the div, what I would like to know is how to navigate to the top of the div not the middle.

I tried to search but everything I found was navigate to the top (of the page), I would like to keep it HTML & CSS only.

Comment: can you please add some online text editor ?

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/m1xr7af1/2/. It goes to the top of the `<div>`..

Comment: the link points correctly to the top of the div: http://jsfiddle.net/qdpnypLh/ ... maybe you think it goes to the middle because there's nothing below it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way would be using another a tag with a name attribute on top of your DIV:

```
<a href="#sol" class="sol"></a>

<a name="sol"></a>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
```